# symfony 1.4 - how to reuse validate method across modules

Tags: symfony-1.4

I have a quite complex validate method in module1/actions.php called from module1/executeMyAction

I would like to reuse this in module2 rather than duplicate very similar code.

It feels like I should use a component or something like this but I don't need to call validate from a template I need to call it as part of the module1/executeMyAction or module2/executeMyAction so I can then set various variables for the executeMyActionSuccess.php template to handlle.

Can anyone let me know how I should reuse this validation code, I considered moving it into the form class but that just means I can't set the template variiables and it seems like it is breaking the MVC structure a bit so I'm not happy with that.

Would really appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to share some parts of code between actions you can create a custom class which will implement some methods you need. You can put the class in the `lib` directory of either the application or the whole project.

E.g. create a `apps/frontend/lib/myUtil.class.php`

```
class myUtil
{
    public static function addNumbers($a, $b)
    {
        return $a + $b;
    }
}
```

Then in your action you can just use:

```
$sum = myUtil::addNumbers(2, 3);
```

If your code depends on some other objects it's best if you don't implement static methods but create an object of the class. E.g.

```
class myUtil
{
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(sfWebRequest $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function sumFromRequest()
    {
        return $this->request->getParameter('a') + $this->request->getParameter('b');
    }
}
```

then in your action

```
public function executeSomething(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $util = new myUtil($request);
    $this->sum = $util->sumFromRequest();
}
```

If your code is strictly used for validation of form fields you can create a custom validator which can be then used in your form. (which will definitely be the best solution). You can read about creating custom validators in the Symfony docs.

Comment: Hi, this seems like  a better appoach than any of mine. The validation method does more than validate, it also processes a transaction, sets template variables etc so not suitable for form. Thanks for your idea, appreciated.